# Why is my query not returning proper results?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to exclude the records that have `channel = all` and `category = Increase Customer Loyalty`. These 2 conditions combined because I have records with this category but different channel. Somewhere in my SQL I am doing something wrong because executing it it excludes all the rows. E.g. all of the records when I expect to see half of them.

```
SELECT * FROM `flows_predefined`
WHERE platform = 'shopify'
AND status = 1
AND (
    category != 'Increase Customer Loyalty'
    AND channel != 'all'
)
ORDER BY `flows_predefined`.`id` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to exclude the records which meet the criteria of

```
    category = 'Increase Customer Loyalty'
    AND channel = 'all'
```

but your where looks to the logical expression that the resulting records should meet. So you need to negate this condition:

```
NOT (
    category = 'Increase Customer Loyalty'
    AND channel = 'all'
}
```

and now let's apply this to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `flows_predefined`
WHERE platform = 'shopify'
AND status = 1
AND NOT (
    category = 'Increase Customer Loyalty'
    AND channel = 'all'
)
ORDER BY `flows_predefined`.`id` DESC;
```

or, if you prefer the `!=` operand:

```
SELECT * FROM `flows_predefined`
WHERE platform = 'shopify'
AND status = 1
AND (
    category = 'Increase Customer Loyalty'
    OR channel = 'all'
)
ORDER BY `flows_predefined`.`id` DESC;
```